# select a different element other than the one clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

How do I select an element with jquery, when a different element is clicked, when you don't know the name of the element? The code below is looping over the all the categories. I don't know how many categories there are, or what the names will be. When the 'insertUrl' link is clicked, I need to select the text area.

The only thing I can thinking is running an function in onclick and passing the name of the text area as a parameter.

Also, I'm not sure that I can use a selector when every link has the same id, so is this even possible?

```
<%
    FullName = objCategory.ID & "|" & objCategory.Name
%>      
<TD COLSPAN="2">
<TEXTAREA ROWS="5" CLASS="formWide" id="<%=FullName %>"><%= objCategory.Text %></TEXTAREA><br />
<a href="#" id="insertUrl">Insert URL</a>
</TD>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML structure stays the same you can use `.prev()`

You shouldn't have elements with the same ID.  You can use classes `class="insertUrl"`

```
<%
  FullName = objCategory.ID & "|" & objCategory.Name
%>      
<TD COLSPAN="2">
  <TEXTAREA ROWS="5" CLASS="formWide" id="<%=FullName %>"><%= objCategory.Text %></TEXTAREA><br />
  <a href="#" class="insertUrl">Insert URL</a>
</TD>
```

and

```
$(".insertUrl").click(function() {
  var textarea = $(this).siblings('textarea');
});
```

Comment: $(this).prev().prev(); works because of the <br>. is that bad practice, or is there a better way?

Comment: changed to use $(this).siblings('textarea'); as TeKapa suggested

Answer (score 1):

maybe its better if you use:

```
$(this).siblings('textarea');
```

this way you have more flexibility with the html controls order.
this way, if you remove the 
 or change something else inside that TD the script will still works.

Answer (score 1):

An even better way would be to use the `<label>` element. This way, you can insert later additional elements between the text comment and the textarea, and it still will work.

```
<textarea id="ta_id1" onclick="click_processing_func"></textarea>
<label for="ta_id1" class="link">Insert Url</label>
```

Now, if anyone clicks on the label, textarea will receive the click event.